# regular expression with multiple negative look behinds for finding text in quotes

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am no expert at regex but basically i want to find all text that is surrounded by quotes, but I want to exclude any matches where the quoted text is prefixed by things like "name=", "type=", "href=", etc. I have about 20 exclusions.
My regex to find all text within quotes is: `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

From what I have read, the negative look behind syntax is: `(?<!text)`
if anyone could provide the regex that would find all text in quotes but ignore any text in quotes that is preceeded by name= or by type=.  I can figure out the rest once i know the correct syntax, if this is even possible. Thanks!

For example, running regex on this string below would return no matches if the regex was configured to look for text within quotes, but only if quote is not preceded by name=, type=, access=, output=.

`<cffunction name="configure" returntype="void" access="public" output="false">`

Comment: Can you provide data sample, and the expected result?

Comment: I added a sample and expected results. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `(?=(\\?))\2`? It's a positive lookahead for a `?` character, then matching that character, so why not just `\\?`? It's the same thing.

Comment: `(?<!name=|type=|access=|output=)(?<==)(["'])(?:[^"'])*\1` See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cKfDSs/1) for demo.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I got the regex for text within quotes from a post here. I am no expert, so I can't spot syntax that is redundant or incorrect..yet.

Answer (score 1):

The positive look behind capture group syntax is `(?<=)`, and the positive look ahead capture group is `(?=)`. Therefore, I believe that a regular expression fitting your goal is `(?<=\W")[^"]*(?="\W)`.

Please note that this will only work if your quoted text if both preceded and followed by spaces or other punctuation sign, so please tweak it to fit your specific case.

Comment: Thanks Archeo, not quite what I want, but it works in that it finds text in strings.  I ended up using positive look behind in my logic. I think that was better than the negative look behind due to far less constraints.